# Representing $100001$ in floating point system

Tags: floating-point

There's an example in my textbook about cancellation error that I'm not totally getting. It says that with a $5$ digit decimal arithmetic, $100001$ cannot be represented.

I think that's because when you try to represent it you get $1*10^5$, which is $100000$. However it goes on to say that when $100001$ is represented in this floating point system (when it's either chopped or rounded) it comes to $100000$.

If what I said above is correct, does $100001$ go to $100000$ because of the fact that it can only be represented like $1*10^5$?

If I'm completely off the mark, clarification would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you only have five decimal digits available.  $100001=1.00001*10^5$ but I have six digits in the mantissa.  Clearly it is closer to go to $1.0000$ than to $1.0001$, so that is what we will do.  So the numbers around here that can be represented are $99998, 99999, 100000, 100010, 100020,$ etc.

Comment: Also on another note would the largest number be 9.9999 * 10^(whatever exp was max)?

Comment: @wzsun:  that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is about the precision of the number that can be stored, not so much the exponent.  In other words you cannot store $1.00001*10^5$ because it cannot store five decimal places of precision.  Equally it would not be able to store $1.00001*10^{15}$ or $1.00001*10^{-5}$.

Answer (score -1):

That is correct. You have what is called type overflow.  Want to be amused?  If you have a C compiler run this program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int x = 1;
    while (x > 0)
    {
        x = x + 1;
    }
    printf("x = %d\n", x);
}
```

It's educational.  This is in integer-world so it's simpler than floating point numbers, but these have an analogous problem: loss of precision. I recommend Forman Acton's `Real Computing Made Real` for a discussion of this issue.

Comment: I don't recall my C very well, but why wouldn't the while fail the first trip through?  It also seems like if your compiler defaults to 32 bit ints you might have a bit of a wait.  Should it print x=-1?

Comment: Note correction. Sorry about the error.

Comment: Integer overflow is a very different situation than floating-point loss of precision.

Comment: It is a similar problem. The bits run off the end and you get in trouble.

Comment: Go look at how IEEE 754 works.